# Arrow link used as page scroll down

Tags: css, joomla

I made a simpel arrow in css:

```
.arrow {
border: solid black;
border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px;
}
```

But how do I insert it as a link. I'm using Joomla. I tried this:

```
<a class="arrow" href="#info"></a>
```

But Joomla just cut that line out. So is it not possible in Joomla or am I doing it wrong? :)

Comment: you just need arrow or its scroll down working ?

Comment: @BilluG The scroll down works fine with a normal link like `<a href="#info">Click here</a>` so I just need the arrows as the link instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click button "Run code snippet" to see arrow or output.

```css
.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-size:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<a class="arrow" href="#info">v</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea, but that was what I wrote too. But Joomla just cut it out, when I don't write anything between the `<a>` and `</a>` :(

Comment: @Daniel Jensen, answer updated, now <a>v</a> have "v" text in it and its style updated, but output will be same, means "v" will not visible.